# pygtk system tray icon doesn't work

Tags: gtk, pygtk, trayicon

i am trying to display system tray icon in my program.
when i start my program it shows window and when i colse window it gets hidden.
Then if i click on system tray icon it shows me a blank window, but not the contents of window.Why is this happen?
Heres the my code:

```
class Main(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main,self).__init__()
        self.set_title("Virtual Machine Monitor")
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.set_default_size(640,600)
        self.set_geometry_hints(min_width=640,min_height=600)
        self.set_icon_from_file("../images/activity_monitor2.png")
        self.connect("destroy",self.window_destroy)
        menubar = self.add_menubar()

        pixbuf = gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file_at_size("../images/activity_monitor2.png",25,25)
        statusicon = gtk.StatusIcon()
        statusicon = gtk.status_icon_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
        statusicon.connect("activate",self.tray_activate)
        self.show_all()

    def tray_activate(self,widget):
        self.show_all()

    def window_destroy(self,widget):
        self.hide_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
    gtk.main()
```

when i click on system tray icon it shows me window , but a blank window.

So please help me out.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must handle `delete-event` to just hide the window and don't destroy that (as by default).

```
class Main(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.connect('delete-event', self.on_delete_event)
        self.set_title("Virtual Machine Monitor")
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.set_default_size(640,600)
        self.set_geometry_hints(min_width=640, min_height=600)
        self.set_icon_from_file("../images/activity_monitor2.png")
        menubar = self.add_menubar()

        pixbuf = gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file_at_size("../images/activity_monitor2.png",25,25)
        statusicon = gtk.StatusIcon()
        statusicon = gtk.status_icon_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
        statusicon.connect("activate",self.tray_activate)
        self.show_all()

    def on_delete_event(self, widget, event):
        self.hide()
        return True    

    def tray_activate(self, widget):
        self.present()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: Minor correction: you don't need to handle "destroy" any more.

Comment: Yes, I did'nt attend to that. Fixed.

Comment: And `show_all()` is not needed in `tray_activate` (since one time `show_all` is called in `__init__`) and `show()` is enough, unless `present()` is better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any controls on your window, I guess you just cut out this code from your snippet. See if the code below would work for you. It should open a window every time you click on the tray icon. Also a popup menu gets registered for the tray.

```
import sys
import gtk

class MainWindow(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.set_title("Virtual Machine Monitor")
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.set_default_size(640, 600)
        self.set_geometry_hints(min_width=640, min_height=600)
        self.set_icon_from_file("../images/activity_monitor2.png")
        self.connect("destroy", self.window_destroy)

        box = gtk.VBox()
        button = gtk.Button("Test Button")
        box.pack_start(button, False)
        self.add(box)

        self.show_all()

    def window_destroy(self,widget):
        self.hide_all()

class TrayIcon(gtk.StatusIcon):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.StatusIcon.__init__(self)

        # using a stock icon, load your pixmap here
        self.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_FIND)
        self.set_tooltip('Tracker Desktop Search')
        self.set_visible(True)

        self.menu = menu = gtk.Menu()

        window_item = gtk.MenuItem("Show Window")
        window_item.connect("activate", self.show_window, "about")
        menu.append(window_item)

        quit_item = gtk.MenuItem("Quit")
        quit_item.connect("activate", self.quit, "file.quit")
        menu.append(quit_item)
        menu.show_all()

        self.connect("activate", self.show_window)
        self.connect('popup-menu', self.icon_clicked)

    def show_window(self, widget, event=None):
        MainWindow()    

    def icon_clicked(self, status, button, time):
        self.menu.popup(None, None, None, button, time)

    def quit(self, widget, event=None):
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TrayIcon() 
    gtk.main()
```